# How to convert QList<QVariant> to QList<T>

Tags: qt

For my serialization method i need to store a `QList<T>` where T is my custom Type, in a QVariantList.

```
QList<T> l;
l.append(T());
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(l);

var.canConvert(QVariant::List);  // returns true
//So i can easily iterate over the variant with sth like this:

QVariantList list;
QSequentialIterable it = var.value<QSequentialIterable>();
for (const QVariant &v : it)
    list << v;

/* deserialization side */
var = list;
var.value<QList<T>>();  //returns an empty list which is not my serialized list;
```

My problem is that i cannot convert back the variant list into `QList<T>`

**EDIT:**

```
#define PROPERTY(type, name) \
    Q_PROPERTY(type name MEMBER name) \
    type name;

class Measurement
{
    Q_GADGET

public:
    PROPERTY(int,       index)
    PROPERTY(QString,   name)
    PROPERTY(QString,   unit)
    PROPERTY(double,    factor)
    PROPERTY(bool,      isVisible)
    PROPERTY(quint8,    decimal)

    bool operator ==(const Measurement &other)
    {
        return (this->index == other.index);
    }
};
```

you can consider this class as my custom type (T). i also save the class name (here "Measurement") along with serialized data for furthur uses, because as you know we can get the registered type with QMetaType::type(char*) but with that type i can only construct a QVariant with QVariant(int typeId, const void *copy) but here i want to construct the `QList<Measurement>` itself.

Comment: You should post a complete program, with any necessary includes and, importantly, any `Q_METATYPE` and related declarations.  Keep it as small as you can - read how to create a [mcve] before you [edit] your question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to `qvariant_cast<QList<T>>(QVariantList)`.  I think you might need to create your own methed to convert member-by-member.

Comment: You are right. But i do not have any access to my <T> in deserialization side. sorry for my misleading question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to deserialize the QVariant list one item at a time. I am also not sure that this line:

```
var = list;
```

is performing what you intended. It will take your QVariantList `list` and wrap it inside another QVariant called `var`, which is of type `QVariant(QVariantList, (QVariant(MyType, ), QVariant(MyType, )))`. There doesn't seem to be much benefit to doing this.

Nonetheless, the example below shows a way to recover the list from `var`.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVariant>

class MyType {
public:
    MyType() {}
    MyType(QString value) { m_value = value; }
    QString m_value;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyType)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QList<MyType> l;
    l.append(MyType("foo"));
    l.append(MyType("bar"));
    QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue(l);

    var.canConvert(QVariant::List);  // returns true
    //So i can easily iterate over the variant with sth like this:

    QVariantList list;
    QSequentialIterable it = var.value<QSequentialIterable>();
    for (const QVariant &v : it)
        list << v;

    /* deserialization side */
    var = list;

    QList<MyType> deserializedList;
    foreach(QVariant v, var.value<QVariantList>()) {
        deserializedList << v.value<MyType>();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So Sorry, I should have put the deserialization side in another function in my question, actually it's in a separated function so i don't have direct access to <MyType>, what i have is only the Type name (as string) and the userType (as int) that is registered with QMetaType. so can i construct a QList<X> in this case?

Comment: Actually the variant list is stored in a file. and when i read the file i have only a qvariantlist and a string representing the type name.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, after reading your new comments, I no longer understand the question. What is `userType`? Why can't you have a definition for `<T>` at the destination?

Comment: please can you provide the code for your custom Type `T`